# Maven repo for Google Drive API down?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

Wanting to use the google drive api in java and maven, I report to the documentation :

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

It indicates this repository:

http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo

The problem is that it is not accessible for me, I get a 404 and maven can't find it (tried in Nexus). Is the repo down or do I miss something?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ok. They just have no browsable content on that URL. I've tried this repository and artifact, and it was fetched successfully.

Comment: It works if I remove nexus, not otherwise.so the problem is in nexus

Comment: Just have to change the proxy options on nexus: Auto Blocking Enabled needs to be set to false

Comment: Sorry about that!  We'll try to change our Maven repo so it serves a 200 instead of a 404.

Comment: We changed this page (http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo) to serve a 200.  Would you kindly check if Nexus works with our Maven repo now with Auto-Blocking disabled?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Auto-Blocking enabled.

Answer (score 2):

As of a few months ago, Google started pushing libraries to the Sonatype repo. You no longer should include a repository entry in your pom.xml pointing to google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo or mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com

Doing that slows down your builds because you end up checking for all dependencies (even non Google ones) at that repository. These checks 404, then you check the master repository.